# Euclidian distance matrix from a set of points

Tags: data

I have a set of points and I like to compute the (pairwise) euclidian distance for those points. The set has a form like this:

`pts = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 5}}`

I need the output as a matrix, because I like to use it for a weighted graph. I noticed that there is a function called `DistanceMatrix[]`, however my Version doesn't support it. 
Is there a easy way using the `EuclideanDistance[]` function ?

Comment: Given the size of my of my set speed is not an issue. Sorry I edit my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of ways to get (symmetric) distance matrix, e.g

```
Outer[EuclideanDistance, pts, pts, 1]
Partition[EuclideanDistance @@@ Tuples[{pts, pts}], 4]
```

[image]

Comment: Whenever I see your post, I try to pronounce your username as ubiquitin, as in the protein

Comment: @JasonB it is an ambigram: rotational symmetry (rotation by $\pi$)- my tiny homage to frugal typograph: only need u and b...:)

Answer (score 2):

**Example:**

```
pts = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 5}};  
Outer[EuclideanDistance, pts, pts] // MatrixForm
```

**Output:**

[image: output example]

**Credits:**

*@Kuba*

**Reference:**

[Outer](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html)

**Tutorials:**

[List Manipulation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html)

Comment: You should add a `1` as the fourth argument to `Outer` so that you have a matrix as the output rather than a `Tensor`.  As it is you are taking the distance between points on the number line (I think) like `EuclideanDistance[{1}, {3}]`

Comment: @JasonB read your comment after posted my answer...oh well

Comment: @JasonB please feel free to edit the post as you find necessary. Your insight is appreciated.

Comment: @Artes, you deleted your comment so maybe you won't see this.  Sorry if my reply came off as harsh, would you care to discuss it in the chat room?